# Will both method execute at same time

Tags: java, synchronization

Assume I have a class with two methods `method1` and `method2`. I have made both of these methods `synchronized`. Assume a class calls `method1` and the same time a different class calls `method2`.  Will both these methods execute at the same time?

Comment: synchronization is about preventing concurrent access to shared state from multiple *threads*. Which class calls the method is irrelevant. What matters is how many threads call the method, and on which object. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: "a class calls method1 and the same time a different class calls method2": Two classes can't do *anything* at the same time unless their code is run in different threads. Have you got multiple threads running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two threads can run two different methods at the same time.  If you use `synchronized` it can limit the threads from running the two method at the same time, if you lock the same object.  However, if your two method synchronize on different objects, they can still be as concurrent.

Answer (score 0):

when you set a syncronized method only one process can use that method at time, this is normally used for concurrence scenarios, the execution of your two differents methods will be executed depending on the process execution in background, so syncronized its only for restrict that two threads execute the same method at the same time. Regards